# FindBugs stopped working after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin from 3.1.3 to 3.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, findbugs

I use FindBugs for static code analysis in my Android projects. The setup is the following:

**quality.gradle**

```
plugins.apply('findbugs')

task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = 'max'
    reportLevel = 'high' // Report only high priority problems.

    classes = files("${project.projectDir}/build/intermediates/classes")
    source = fileTree('src/main/java')

    classpath = files()

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
    }

    excludeFilter = rootProject.file('quality/findbugs.xml')
}
```

**build.gradle**:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        project.apply from: '../quality/quality.gradle'
        tasks.findByName('findbugs').dependsOn('assemble')
        tasks.findByName('check').dependsOn('findbugs')
    }
}
```

But after I upgraded the Gradle Android Plugin from 3.1.3 to 3.2.0 the build started failing:

```
./gradlew clean build

> Task :app:findbugs FAILED
No files to be analyzed

...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:findbugs'.
> Failed to run Gradle FindBugs Worker
   > Process 'Gradle FindBugs Worker 6' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Downgrading to 3.1.3 makes the build pass again. I haven't found anything related in the [changelog](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-2-0) of the Gradle Android Plugin. Can anybody point me out what's wrong with the plugin or my setup?

Comment: Have you tried stopping the Gradle daemon? `./gradlew --stop`, then try again.

Comment: @stkent sorry, it didn't help, same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a short investigation, I found out that the location of Java class files has changed from `build/intermediates/classes` to `build/intermediates/javac`. The new FindBugs configuration:

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ...
    classes = files("${project.projectDir}/build/intermediates/javac")
   ...
}
```

The strange thing that this breaking change isn't mentioned in the Android Gradle Plugin [changelog](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-2-0), or in the Gradle [changelog](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html).

Comment: This was truly helpful. Spent couple of hours trying to figure what this error: *Failed to run Gradle FindBugs Worker* and after much search, I found this answer. A big thank you!

Comment: I will add that `findbugs` thankfully does a good job of posting good debug info to help diagnose issues. Your answer helped me but I had one other problem with my script (which was my own error) that I ran with `--debug` on and it did wonders.